# How to make singular instance of text editable in a template

Tags: channel-entries, templates, custom-fields

Is there a good workflow for making a singular instance of text, like an intro paragraph, editable within a template?

I find this comes up a lot and the channel entry workflow is really built around multiples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For times where the Channel module is overkill, or the random bits of editable content don't really fit the Channel mould, [Low Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-variables) is really great.

It has a lot of added features beyond just making global variables easily (and safely) editable by end users. Some of the big benefits are text formatting options, custom content types for the global variable (this is huge!), early parsing, and save global variables as files.

Comment: I've heard of the plugin and after looking it over on DevotEE it seems like the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

For basic copy, you can accomplish this using native [**Snippets**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/snippets.html).

> Snippets are small bits of reusable template or tag parts. You could
>   create a Snippet for any number of purposes, anywhere that you need to
>   reuse a small portion of a template, including partial or complete
>   tags, other variables, etc. Snippets add flexibility and reusability,
>   while making it simple to make site-wide changes by editing the
>   Snippet’s source instead of having to modify many templates.

Comment: ...or native Global Variables. This approach does come with the potential downside of needing to give the end-user unrestricted access to both Snippets and Global Variables in the CP.

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl, thank you. Low Variables looks ideal, but staying native in EE for cases where formatting and access don't matter as much this is a great suggestion.